# Get details about Reply/Forward message's parent email in Outlook in Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

In Python, I try to fetch the 'Sent Items' with parent's subject of that mail in **OUTLOOK** using **win32com.client**. If sent mail is replied mail or forwarded mail means, I want following,

```
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Sent Items")
inbox_messages = inbox.Items
for msg in inbox_messages:
  print(msg.Subject)
```

I'm getting following output:

```
Re: This is replied Email (some this edited)
```

Actually, I want to print the Original parent mail's Subject. That is

```
This is replied Email
```

Even that subject make edit/or update, want original one. Please give with some example code.

Comment: Do you just want the subject? Or the whole original message in the Sent Items folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conversations in Outlook to navigate to the original email and get the original subject line from the first one. Other than that the Outlook object model doesn't provide anything. You may try to use a low-level API on which is Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or any third-party wrapper around that API such as Redemption. In that case you may get the `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT` property value which contains the message subject with any prefix removed.

The [MailItem.GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs. Here is the sample code in C# (the Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages):

```
void DemoConversation() 
{ 
 object selectedItem = 
 Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]; 
 // This example uses only 
 // MailItem. Other item types such as 
 // MeetingItem and PostItem can participate 
 // in the conversation. 
 if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 // Cast selectedItem to MailItem. 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 // Determine the store of the mail item. 
 Outlook.Folder folder = mailItem.Parent 
 as Outlook.Folder; 
 Outlook.Store store = folder.Store; 
 if (store.IsConversationEnabled == true) 
 { 
 // Obtain a Conversation object. 
 Outlook.Conversation conv = 
 mailItem.GetConversation(); 
 // Check for null Conversation. 
 if (conv != null) 
 { 
 // Obtain Table that contains rows 
 // for each item in the conversation. 
 Outlook.Table table = conv.GetTable(); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items Count: " + 
 table.GetRowCount().ToString()); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Table:"); 
 while (!table.EndOfTable) 
 { 
 Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow(); 
 Debug.WriteLine(nextRow["Subject"] 
 + " Modified: " 
 + nextRow["LastModificationTime"]); 
 } 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Root:"); 
 // Obtain root items and enumerate the conversation. 
 Outlook.SimpleItems simpleItems 
 = conv.GetRootItems(); 
 foreach (object item in simpleItems) 
 { 
 // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (item is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mail = item 
 as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mail.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mail.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Call EnumerateConversation 
 // to access child nodes of root items. 
 EnumerateConversation(item, conv); 
 } 
 } 
 } 
 } 
} 
 
 
void EnumerateConversation(object item, 
 Outlook.Conversation conversation) 
{ 
 Outlook.SimpleItems items = 
 conversation.GetChildren(item); 
 if (items.Count > 0) 
 { 
 foreach (object myItem in items) 
 { 
 // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (myItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 myItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mailItem.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Continue recursion. 
 EnumerateConversation(myItem, conversation); 
 } 
 } 
}
```